# Csvsimple with colored rows gives black cell in the next table

Tags: tables, luatex, csvsimple

What is wrong with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Overwriting file}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
HH,GG
X1,Y1
X2,Y2
X3,Y3
X4,Y4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[tabular={ll}, no head, late after head=\\\rowcolor{yellow},
late after line=\csvifoddrow{\\\rowcolor{yellow}}{\\}] {test.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lll}
header & header & header \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

That it gives me:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't nothing wrong. You only used the package example, I think that the culprit is the package since this function should be used with other options. I'll try to explain myself. In your example, you put some options after the row ends. I don't know why, but if you put an option after the last line of a table, this option affect the first line of the next table. Obviously putting an option after the last line of a table is wrong, but I don't know why it affects the first line of the following table.

In fact, if you ad another line of data, you don't have this problem anymore.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Overwriting file}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
HH,GG
X1,Y1
X2,Y2
X3,Y3
X4,Y4
X5,Y5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[tabular={ll}, no head, late after head=\\\rowcolor{yellow},
late after line=\csvifoddrow{\\\rowcolor{yellow}}{\\}] {test.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}%

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lll}
header & header & header \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: example_with_one_more_line_of_data]

To avoid this fact I propose to you another approach based on the oddity of the lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% Add option table
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Overwriting file}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
HH,GG
X1,Y1
X2,Y2
X3,Y3
X4,Y4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[tabular={ll}, no head] {test.csv}{}%
{\csvifoddrow%
  {\cellcolor{yellow}\csvcoli&\cellcolor{yellow}\csvcolii}%
  {\csvcoli&\csvcolii}%
}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lll}
header & header & header \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Note that I loaded `xcolor` with the option `table` to color the cell.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am a `csvsimple` newbie. Could I come up with your solution just by scanning the package tutorial? Further, loading `xcolor` without the `table` option also works. What benefit does it provide (at least, in this case)?

Comment: My example is just the one before yours in the package distribution. The only difference is that that one is about bold fonts. Loading the package `xcolor` with `table` gives you the possibility to use `\cellcolor`. I don't know if there is any command in `csvsimple` that perform the same task, this is the first time that I see `csvsimple` package. :)